# How do I join two SQLite tables with the Android API?

Tags: android, sqlite

I like to use the query method instead of rawQuery because it is more elegant for me, but it seems that the method can receive only one table as an input parameter.

Is there a solution for many tables?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there's any other method which can offer you this flexibility. Thats why the API comes with the method `rawQuery()`. Use sql query using `UNION` to join data from two tables.

for example:

```
String query = "SELECT Id, Name FROM Finance " + 
               "UNION ALL " +
               "SELECT Id, Name FROM Marketing";

Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
```

Comment: So I'm stuck with rawQuery. Then I'll use that. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: yes, i assume the only way to achieve this without using any sqlite feature is to use **rawQuery**. And there's nothing wrong to use it as long as it does exactly what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

Best will be just using `rawquery`, but if you must stick with `query`:

( please note, I have not tested this, but I imagine it will work )

You should be able to create a view ( http://sqlite.org/lang_createview.html ) and then use the view name in place of a table name.